# How to implement interface method with different type parameter

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, interface

**tl;dr**

I need to have `TypeInterface::generateId(<object> $doc)` where the `<object>` is different for each class that implements the interface.
How can/should I achieve this?

---

Hi guys

I'm wrecking my head with this.

I have an interface (`TypeInterface`) which needs to have a method like `TypeInterface::generateId(Document $doc)` that will return a generated id from the doc specs, so far so good.

**the problem**

The several documents have methods in common, like `::schema()`, but all the properties are specific for each one.
So from this I made the following interfaces

- DocumentInterface - holds the methods that all documents must have
- ObjectAInterface - holds the methods for the properties of Document type A
- ObjectBInterface - holds the methods for the properties of Document type B

So the class TypeA (which implements `TypeInterface`) generates the ID with some properties/methods of ObjectAInterface that ObjectBInterface doesn't have for the TypeB class

I intended to do:

```
public function getDocument(TypeInterface $core, DocumentInterface $document)
{
  $this->client->index([
    'index' => $core->getIndex()->name(),
    'type' => $core->name(),
    'id' => $core->generateId($document), // HERE!
    'body' => $core->schema(),
  ]);
}
```

So the `$core->generateId($document)` should be generic to work with all `TypeInterface` but also the specific TypeA should have some kind of relation with the DocumentA.

Questions:

- How can I achieve this?
- Best practices in these cases?
- Maybe I'm just thinking in this wrongly, and there is a better way to do this, or not at all

**code**

I've created a simple gist with the example code
https://gist.github.com/MLoureiro/13cb336bc22ce330511f